# How to apply Fubini's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I was asked to show the equality of these integrals 
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\log(4+\sin x)dydx
  =\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\log(4+\sin x)dxdy\tag{1}$$
Which can be answered by using Fubini's theorem but in order to use Fubini here is what I did

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\log(4+\sin x)$. Now

\begin{align*}
|f(x,y)|&= \biggl|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\log(4+\sin x)\biggl|\\
        &\leq \log5\biggl|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\biggl|\\
        &\leq\log 5\biggl(\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\biggl)=\frac{\log5}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}:=g(x,y)
\end{align*}
To apply Tonelli Theorem on a non negative function 
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\log5}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}dxdy\tag{2}$$
This is the part I get stuck. If the above integral in $(2)$ is finite, then we can apply Fubini and $(1)$ follows immediately.  Is my choice of $g(x,y)$ fine? If so, how can I evaluate $(2)$. But if not, what is the best choice to bound $|f(x,y)|$?

Comment: $g(x,y) = \frac{C}{|x^2+y^2|^{1/2}}$ is a perfect choice, if you think to $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 g(x,y) dx dy < \iint_{x^2+y^2 < 2} g(x,y) dxdy = \int_0^2 \int_0^{2 \pi} g(r \cos\theta,r \sin\theta) d\theta r dr $  (and note how this Fubini theorem follows exactly the same idea as when proving  the order of summation doesn't matter for absolutely convergent series)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: change to polar coordinates.

Comment: $\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}dxdy=\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^\sqrt{2}drd \theta=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$  did I made any mistake?

Comment: I believe the upper limit for $r$ should be $1/\sin \theta$ and should multiply it by 2 since you only consider the angle from $0$ to $\pi/4$.

Comment: @albo, you can't turn a square into a circular sector like you seemingly deed in your limits.

Comment: @YuriyS: could show me how to do that?

Comment: @albo: to describe the unit square $[0,1]^2$ in polar coordinates, use symmetry and consider the triangle under the line $y=x$; then $\theta$ ranges from zero to $\pi/4$ while $r$ ranges from 0 to the line $x=1$, which in polar coordinates is $r\cos\theta=1$, so $r=\sec\theta$. this is overkill, though. the unit square lies in the disk of radius $\sqrt{2}$, centered at be origin, and obviously your integral is finite on that disk.